# class instantiation for use across all models in Laravel3

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel

I am using Laravel 3 (new to it).  I have an API helper class that I'm using as a library.  I want to have that class instantiated so I can use it within all my models to access the API.  I am struggling with figuring out how to do it without instantiating it once in each model.  An example would be awesome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can go about doing this, the easiest would probably be just creating a `base` model where you instantiate the API helper class, then extending that base model for all of the models which you want to access the API.

It might look something like:

```
// base.php
class Base {

    public static function api()
    {
        return new YourApiClass;
    }

}

// user.php
class User extends Base {

    public static function name()
    {
        return parent::api()->callApiMethod();
    }

}
```

You could also use [Laravel 3's IoC container](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc), which might be the better choice depending on what you are doing.

Comment: This helps, thanks.  What if I used an IoC container in the base class within a constructor and then try to use it in the other models?

Comment: Sure you could do that.  [Here is some additional information about IoC containers](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/ioc-container) which could shed some additional light on where and how to use them.

Comment: I don't think this matches the motboys need. I think he wants one instance to be shared across all the models. By adding it to the base model you are still creating a new instance per model. I think the IoC container is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use an IoC container.

Instantiate your class:

```
IoC::register('mailer', function()
{
    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

    return Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
});
```

And then when you need to access your instance you just have to:

```
IoC::instance('mailer', $instance);
```

Reference: http://laravel.com/docs/ioc

Comment: How do I resolve it once so I can use the instance in all the class methods?  Constructor?